# В чем логика закрытия «домашних заданий»?

Tags: обсуждение

В своих действиях нужно придерживаться определенных целей. Какова же **цель форума** в закрытии «домашних заданий»?

Поставим вопрос так: в чем наша конечная заинтересованность? Я полагаю, что это **высокая посещаемость, престижность, большое количество интересных вопросов.**

И вот **с интересными вопросами  в Сети как-то не очень получается.**  Самые лучшие из них даже дублируются на разных сайтах, в том числе эти вопросы «списывают»  и  у нас. Казалось бы, надо активно работать в этом направлении, ведь даже в «домашних заданиях» встречаются неплохие темы, на которые и ответишь-то не сразу.  **В конце концов, их можно отредактировать под наш профиль  и извлечь из них максимальную пользу.**

А что делаем мы? Мы их закрываем в воспитательных целях. Но, как мне кажется,  воспитание – это не наш профиль,  так зачем нам решать чьи-то чужие задачи, когда у нас своих достаточно.

Вот последний пример – закрытие вопроса **об итоговом сочинении**. Очень популярная сейчас тема,  так зачем же ее закрывать? Зато другие учебные сайты с удовольствием перепишут и вопрос, и ответ.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462861/Как-сформулировать-тезис-и-зачин-в-итоговом-сочинении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462861/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)